# Codeigniter SSH Connection to remote MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, ssh

I am trying to connect to our live Database remotely using Codeigniter. However I'm getting an error:

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.54.9.20' (using password: YES)

**Database.php config file:**

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'database',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => TRUE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE, //tried changing this to TRUE
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I have no issue using the DB in my localhost however getting errors when using remote config.

Need help. Thanks guys!

Comment: you probably need some GRANTS

Comment: Hi Drew,

Yes as 1000111 said on his comment down. But Im not sure where to run this command.

I tried accessing the server via SSH but GRANT isn't recognized as a command.

It says:
If 'grant' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it.... etc.

Comment: Been asked a jillion times and answered too! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login from localhost and run the following commands:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now try to gain access remotely.

Comment: Should i do this via terminal accessing the server? or through code?

Comment: I tried accessing the server through SSH, and grant isn't recognized as a valid command. I am at lost as to where to do this. Im sorry.

Comment: Don't you have the `root` user access?

Comment: Yes I have. I was able to login via terminal using SSH using the root access.

When I try to run the command it says " If 'grant' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it.... etc."

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root'`. See if you have `grant` privilege

Comment: Okay ran the query and here's what i got:

HOST: localhost
User: root
Password: BLANK
Other fields are set to Y (YES)
except for password_expired and is_role which is N.

Comment: Worth noting that I have ran GRANT on Mysql
Here's the results:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: HI! 

IT WORKED! WOW! Amazing! Will take a note of this!
Thank you SO MUCH, man! Intense! It's my first time with PHP surely is a noob and with MySQL.

You are AWESOME!

Comment: This is not a solution yet. The question is asking how to configure the connect via SSH in CI. It has not been supported natively in the CI config file yet. If it worked, it should have been something wrong with your firewall... The reason you can connect via terminal since your machine has been verified by Server via your shared public key and private key in your local. But the local site cannot access your local machine private key without config it.

Answer (score 0):

That combination of username, host, and password is not allowed to connect to the server. Verify the permission tables (reloading grants if required) on the server and that you're connecting to the correct server.

Comment: alright show him how to do that. You are now on the hook :p

Comment: Thanks. However, how do I do that? it's a bit complicated on my end especially with remote DB's with SSH authentications.

Comment: I am able to remotely access the server via terminal using SSH using the password and username (user and pw for the server is the same with the database since I was able to connect MySQLyog using the same information).